# Unexpected RightToLeft String concatenation

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio-2010, globalization, string-concatenation

Lets say I have a `DataRow` with a number of columns like this,

```
//header

firstnameEnglish , FirstNameArabic, LastnameEnglish , LastNameArabic, 
project, addressEnglish, addressِArabic

//data'hatem', 'حاتم', 'gamil','جميل','||',
```

'11 el haram street ','11 الهرم'

I want to get the row data in a string where I can export it to a text file.

I do a `for` loop on the `DataRow` columns something like this,

```
string data = String.Empty;    

for(int i=0; i < datarow.columns.count<0; i++)
    datastr += datarow[i] + " | ";
```

My problem is, the string in `data` is concatenated the wrong way. After debugging, I found that the concatenation is going well until concatenating the `addressEnglish` to the `data`. At this point `data` already contains the values from the concatenated columns up to and including the arabic columns.

The output is,

```
'hatem', 'حاتم', 'gamil', 'جميل','||',  '11 ELHaram street','11 شارع الهرم'
```

which is wrong.

I want to know why is this happing and how to solve this

Thanks

Comment: As an interesting 'meta' issue, the RightToLeft nature of the arabic text made editing the OP very "interesting".

Comment: so do u have any suggestions or a work around to solve this

Comment: I don't see any problem - your 'data' is in the same order as your 'output', except '1 ' is replaced with '11'. Can you please clarify this?

Comment: I couldn't say with any authority, but obviously the text you've pasted is arabic and would normally be read from RightToLeft. Unfortunately my knowlegde of arabic is abyssmal so I can't even guess what the right way would be or to be honest, that my edit has not altered the definition of the problem a little. However, I notice the downvote has been matched.

Comment: Its not entirely impossible that our browsers are rendering the post differently depending on our Culture and Locality.

Comment: @kirk BroadHurst kindly check the post again and u will see the difference between data in datarow and output ( i have to make the data in 2 lines or it will display in wrong way same as output i dont know y)

Comment: @jordell thanks for editing ,,and yes ur editing changes the way data is showen it makes it looks like the output which is wrong

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's not a matter of the program you're using to display you results on the screen? Since Arabic is right-to-left, Unicode-aware programs often use heuristics to decide how much of the punctuation surrounding the Arabic phrase it should render right-to-left together with it.

A character-by-character dump would make it easier to be sure that there is actually a problem to solve.

(Conversely, are you sure that the punctuation in the input csv is stored in the right order?)

Comment: yes i am sure this issue is not related to the program i am using to display my results ,,i am using notepad,,and while debugging the value of the string after concatenation is worng,,so do u have any suggestions

Comment: Why are you so sure that notepad is not doing any fancy RTL processing?

Comment: lets say it is an issue in nodepad ,,i tried to write string that i want to get as an output in notepad and unexpected behavior happens ,,so do you have any suggestions how i can handle something like that

Comment: My suggestion, as given in the answer, is to do character-for-character dumps (with hex representation of non-ascii codepoints) instead of displaying the Unicode as strings. Only then can you be completely sure which data your program is working on.

Comment: can u please send me how i can do that hex representation of non asci codepounts